# Replace keys in an object array, with array of keys changing dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapreduce, key

I have two arrays as follows,

**columnNames** = ['KEY_ID', 'SOURCE_ID', 'MTNAME', 'MTNO', 'PLANTS']

**columnValues** = [{col0:"719801", col1: "4198", col2: "010", col3: "200887", col4: "6LLA"},
{col0:"719901", col1: "5198", col2: "011", col3: "207887", col4: "6PPA"}]

My expected output is,

**outputArray** = [{KEY_ID:"719801", SOURCE_ID: "4198", MTNAME: "010", MTNO: "200887", PLANTS: "6LLA"},
{KEY_ID:"719901", SOURCE_ID: "5198", MTNAME: "011", MTNO: "207887", PLANTS: "6PPA"}]

The number of items and contents of both arrays change dynamically i.e., **columnNames** can have different names and **columnValues** can have any number of values. Any inputs to obtain the final **outputArray** will be highly helpful.
I have tried using *reduce*. It either requires multiple iterations or the **columnNames** array to be constant.

```js
let renameKeys = (columnValues, object) =>
    Object.keys(object).reduce(
      (acc, key) => ({
        ...acc,
        ...{ [columnValues[key] || key]: object[key] },
      }),
      {}
    );        

 console.log(renameKeys(columnNames,columnValues))
```

Comment: Please show the output when there are more columnNames than columnValues and vice versa

Comment: You do not have an object, you have a weird array. I made a snippet and changed the  columnValues to an object

Comment: should columnValues be a json object? It is in square brackets, like an array, but contains key/value pairs, like an object.

Comment: columnValues is an array of such objects. I am adding more values to clear the picture.

Comment: @MaruthiRevankar I added an answer, Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output array is not valid. It should be an array of objects. You can achieve this requirement by iterating the input array with the help of [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Live Demo **:**

```js
const columnNames = ['KEY_ID', 'SOURCE_ID', 'MTNAME', 'MTNO', 'PLANTS'];

const columnValues = [{col0:"719801", col1: "4198", col2: "010", col3: "200887", col4: "6LLA"}, {col0:"719901", col1: "5198", col2: "011", col3: "207887", col4: "6PPA"}];

columnValues.forEach(obj => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, index) => {
    obj[columnNames[index]] = obj[key]
    delete obj[key];
  });
});

console.log(columnValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you !

```js
let columnNames = ['KEY_ID', 'SOURCE_ID', 'MTNAME', 'MTNO', 'PLANTS']
let columnValues = [{col0:"719801", col1: "4198", col2: "010", col3: "200887", col4: "6LLA"}, {col0:"719901", col1: "5198", col2: "011", col3: "207887", col4: "6PPA"}]

renameKey = (obj, old_key, new_key) => {   
          // check if old key = new key  
              if (old_key !== new_key) {                  
                 Object.defineProperty(obj, new_key, // modify old key
                                      // fetch description from object
                 Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, old_key));
                 delete obj[old_key];                // delete old key
                 }
          }

columnValues.map((cv)=>{
Object.keys(cv).map((keys,index)=>{
   renameKey(cv,keys,columnNames[index])
  })
})
console.log(columnValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your columnValues is not an object as it has square brackets

This will ONLY work if there are as many names as values:

```js
const columnNames = ['KEY_ID', 'SOURCE_ID', 'MTNAME', 'MTNO', 'PLANTS'],
columnValues = {col0:"719801", col1: "4198", col2: "010", col3: "200887", col4: "6LLA"}
let renameKeys = (columnValues, object) => 
  Object.values(object).reduce((acc, val, i) => {
    acc[columnNames[i]] = val;
    return acc}, 
  {});


console.log(renameKeys(columnNames, columnValues))
```